# Asio no response afer sending a basic http request

Tags: c++, asio

I'm new to asio and was follwing a tutorial. After sending a pretty basic http get request to example.com there is no response.

```
#include<json/json.h>
#include<asio/ts/buffer.hpp>
#include<asio/ts/internet.hpp>
#include<iostream>

#define ASIO_STANDALONE

int main(){
    asio::error_code ec;
    asio::io_context context;
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("93.184.216.34", ec), 80);
    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(context);
    socket.connect(endpoint, ec);
    
    std::cout << ec.message() << '\n';

    if(socket.is_open())
    {
        std::string sRequest = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
        std::cout << sRequest.data();
        socket.write_some(asio::buffer(sRequest.data(), sRequest.size()), ec);
    
        int bytes = socket.available();
        std::cout << bytes << '\n';

        if(bytes > 0)
        {
            std::vector<char> vBuffer(bytes);
            socket.read_some(asio::buffer(vBuffer.data(), vBuffer.size()), ec);

            for(auto c : vBuffer)
            {
                std::cout << c;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What is weird is that from tcpdump it seems that there was a response sent back.

```
16:53:57.116316 IP arch.44680 > 93.184.216.34.http: Flags [S], seq 999815019, win 32120, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2462554605 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:53:57.173058 IP arch.35949 > _gateway.domain: 48878+ PTR? 34.216.184.93.in-addr.arpa. (44)
16:53:57.193671 IP _gateway.domain > arch.35949: 48878 NXDomain 0/1/0 (115)
16:53:57.236277 IP 93.184.216.34.http > arch.44680: Flags [S.], seq 729800927, ack 999815020, win 65535, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 3857096832 ecr 2462554605,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:53:57.236306 IP arch.44680 > 93.184.216.34.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 2462554725 ecr 3857096832], length 0
16:53:57.236454 IP arch.44680 > 93.184.216.34.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:52, ack 1, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 2462554726 ecr 3857096832], length 51: HTTP: GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
16:53:57.236490 IP arch.44680 > 93.184.216.34.http: Flags [F.], seq 52, ack 1, win 251, options [nop,nop,TS val 2462554726 ecr 3857096832], length 0
16:53:57.357833 IP 93.184.216.34.http > arch.44680: Flags [.], ack 52, win 128, options [nop,nop,TS val 3857096953 ecr 2462554726], length 0
16:53:57.358428 IP 93.184.216.34.http > arch.44680: Flags [P.], seq 1:1613, ack 53, win 128, options [nop,nop,TS val 3857096953 ecr 2462554726], length 1612: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
16:53:57.358429 IP 93.184.216.34.http > arch.44680: Flags [F.], seq 1613, ack 53, win 128, options [nop,nop,TS val 3857096953 ecr 2462554726], length 0
16:53:57.358458 IP arch.44680 > 93.184.216.34.http: Flags [R], seq 999815072, win 0, length 0
16:53:57.358487 IP arch.44680 > 93.184.216.34.http: Flags [R], seq 999815072, win 0, length 0
```

Comment: Independent of the answer, consider using boost asio instead of "plain" asio -- that way, you can also use boost beast to do http stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    std::vector<char> vBuffer(bytes);
```

Your vector is empty because `bytes` is a [TOCTOU race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). You printed `bytes`, and it is likely 0. At least, for me it is:

```
Success
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close

0
```

Instead, accept a dynamic read until `"\r\n\r\n"`:

```
std::vector<char> vBuffer;
read_until(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(vBuffer), "\r\n\r\n", ec);
```

Actually, you *need* to do the same on the write, because `write_some` may write only part of the message. Also, don't manually specify the buffer and size, reducing room for errors.

E.g. **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47c9178c746e7ee3)**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

#if 0
    #include <asio.hpp>
    #define ASIO_STANDALONE
    using asio::error_code;
#else
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    namespace asio = boost::asio;
    using boost::system::error_code;
#endif

int main() {
    using asio::ip::tcp;
    error_code       ec;
    asio::io_context context;
    tcp::socket      socket(context);
    socket.connect({asio::ip::make_address("93.184.216.34", ec), 80}, ec);

    std::cout << ec.message() << '\n';

    if (socket.is_open()) {
        std::string sRequest = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
        write(socket, asio::buffer(sRequest), ec);

        std::vector<char> vBuffer;
        auto n = read_until(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(vBuffer), "\r\n\r\n", ec);

        auto headers = std::span(vBuffer).subspan(0, n);
        for (auto c : headers) {
            std::cout << c;
        }
    }
}
```

Showing

[image]

### Out of the box

Of course, now you woud need to parse the headers, get the content-length, read the body (taking into account the part of the body that was **already** received in `vBuffer`).

That's only scratching the surface because the response may use chunked encoding.

You have to implement all that.

**OR** you could use a library like Beast to do it for you instead of reinventing the wheel (likely with security vulnerabilities).

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46676243fb51ecb0)**

```cpp
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace http = boost::beast::http;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::system_error;

int main() try {
    asio::io_context context;
    tcp::socket      socket(context);
    socket.connect({asio::ip::make_address("93.184.216.34"), 80});

    http::request<http::empty_body> req(http::verb::get, "/", 11);
    req.set(http::field::host, "example.com");
    req.set(http::field::connection, "close");
    req.prepare_payload(); // not required, there's no body, but for instructional value

    write(socket, req);

    http::response<http::string_body> res;
    boost::beast::flat_buffer buf;
    read(socket, buf, res);

    std::cout << res.base() << std::endl; // headers
    if (res.chunked())
        std::cout << "Response used chunked encoding" << std::endl;
    std::string body = std::move(res.body());
    std::cout << "The body size is " << body.length() << std::endl;
    // std::cout << body << std::endl;
} catch (system_error const& se) {
    std::cerr << "Error: " << se.code().message() << '\n';
}
```

Printing e.g.

[image]

Comment: Added the Beast implementation for comparison https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46676243fb51ecb0